# !: exclamation mark colon

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am researching about making a Vue component using class and found out this library

https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#Provide

In the example as below:

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop(Number) readonly propA: number | undefined
  @Prop({ default: 'default value' }) readonly propB!: string
  @Prop([String, Boolean]) readonly propC: string | boolean | undefined
}
```

What is the !: meaning in the code

`propB!: string`

Comment: That's not JS. Most likely TypeScript.

Comment: It is typescript. It says so at the top of the page the OP linked to in the question